Notification Service Extension is not getting triggered using FCM with Flutter
I'm trying to update the content of the notification before showing the banner. Like decrypting the message and then showing it. Just like the use case they've demoed in the Apple Developer Docs. In the example, they're using APNS Payload, so I changed it for FCM.
I'm sending the FCM payload via Amazon SNS: Mobile Push Notifications.
{
    "GCM": {
        "notification": {
            "title": "Sample message for Android endpoints",
            "body": "(Encrypted)",
            "mutable_content": true,
            "category": "SECRET"
        },
        "data": {
            "ENCRYPTED_DATA": "Salted__·öîQÊ$UDì_¶Ù∞èΩ^¬%gq∞NÿÒQùw",
            "imageUrl": "https://picsum.photos/200/300"
        },
        "aps": {
            "alert": {
                "title": "Title",
                "body": "Body"
            },
            "mutable-content": 1
        }
    }
}

When testing with this payload, I'm receiving Remote Notifications in the Flutter App but the Notification Service Extension is not getting triggered at all. I checked it by having a breakpoint and a print statement inside the didReceive override. This is what I'm seeing in Firebase onMessage listener when a Remote Notification is received (even without adding aps dictionary in the payload).
flutter: FCM Category: SECRET
flutter: FCM Mutable Content: true
flutter: FCM Content Available: false
flutter: FCM Message Type: null
flutter: FCM Notification: Instance of 'RemoteNotification'
flutter: FCM Data: {ENCRYPTED_DATA: Salted__·öîQÊ$UDì_¶Ù∞èΩ^¬%gq∞NÿÒQùw, imageUrl: https://picsum.photos/200/300}

Here's NotificationService.swift
//
//  NotificationService.swift
//  AppNotificationServiceExtension
//
//  Created by Rohit Kokate on 07/05/24.
//

import UserNotifications
import FirebaseMessaging

class NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension {

    var contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?
    var bestAttemptContent: UNMutableNotificationContent?

    override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
        self.contentHandler = contentHandler
        bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)
        
        print("UNNotificationRequest : \(bestAttemptContent?.title ?? "default")")
        
        if let bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent {
            // Modify the notification content here...
            bestAttemptContent.title = "\(bestAttemptContent.title) [modified]"
            
//            contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
            Messaging.serviceExtension().populateNotificationContent(bestAttemptContent, withContentHandler: contentHandler)

        }
    }
    
    override func serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire() {
        // Called just before the extension will be terminated by the system.
        // Use this as an opportunity to deliver your "best attempt" at modified content, otherwise the original push payload will be used.
        if let contentHandler = contentHandler, let bestAttemptContent =  bestAttemptContent {
            contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
        }
    }

}

Added Firebase/Messaging under Notification Service Extension target at the end of my Podfile.
target 'AppNotificationServiceExtension' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
end

I've ensured that

Deployment Targets of the project and the service match
'Copy only when installing' is unchecked in Embed Foundation Extension in Build Phases.
Adding aps dictionary with alert in the payload
I've tried restarting the device
I've gone through similar SO questions without any success

PS: From Firebase, I've seen documentation related to Notification Service Extension only involving Sending an image in the Notification. And nothing for other use cases.

Did you manage to resolve the issue?

No, I did not. @prg.dev

@RohitKokate, did you get any solution for this??

@prg.dev, are you able to resolve this as I am also getting same issue.
